# Find the $rank(AB)$ when rank of $A$ and $B$ are given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let , $A_{7\times 5}$ be a matrix of rank $3$ and $B_{5\times 7}$ be a matrix of rank $5$. Then find the rank of the matrix $AB$.

As we know , $rank(AB)\le\min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$ , so $rank(AB)\le 3$. But how I can find out the exact value of $rank(AB)$ ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: This implies that the image of $AB$ is exactly the image of $A$.

Comment: @  user1551) How ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I have given enough hints. At any rate, the key points are (1) $B$ is surjective, (2) the rank of a linear map is the dimension of its image.

Comment: Furthermore, it might help to reformulate the matrix multiplication as a mapping: Instead of "what is the rank of AB?", think "what is the rank of $f\circ g$?"

Comment: @ 1510001267) I know this...As , $B$ is onto so $B(\mathbb R^7)=\mathbb R^5$ and then $AB(\mathbb R^7)=A(\mathbb R^5)=?$

Comment: @Panja you are told $\dim A(\mathbb R^5)=3$, but you basically just said that is also $\dim AB(\mathbb R^7)$, which is exaclty he rank of $AB$. So the rank of the product is 0. No matter what the actual image is, that won't interest you. See also the answer by anomaly below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The rank also satisfies the so called Sylvester’s rank inequality:

If A is an $m \times n$ matrix and B is $n \times k$, then
$$rank(AB) \geq rank(A)+ rank(B) -n$$

Comment: I know this inequality holds for two square matrices of same order. Is it also hold for $m\times n$ and $n\times k$ matrices ?

Comment: @Panja717 Yes..

Answer (score 5):

Consider $A, B$ as linear maps $A:\mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^7$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^7 \to \mathbb{R}^5$. Then, by definition, $\operatorname{rk}(A) = \dim \operatorname{im}(A)$ and $\operatorname{rk}(B) = \dim \operatorname{im}(B)$. In particular, $B$ is surjective. Hence $\operatorname{im} AB = A(\operatorname{im B}) = \operatorname{im}(A)$, and $\operatorname{rk} AB = \dim \operatorname{im} AB = \dim \operatorname{im} A = \operatorname{rk} A$.

Comment: Anyone want to comment on why this was downvoted?