# Finding Rank of Product of Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Size and Rank of Matrix A is given as 10 * 3 and 3 respectively.
Actual/Full Matrix B is given which is of size 3 * 3 and I am able to find that the rank of B is also 3.

I have to find the actual rank of the product matrix AB.

I understand that rank(AB)≤min(rank A,rank B) as per theorem. But need help to find the exact rank.

Comment: Try and show $\text{Col}(AB)=\text{Col}(A)$ by using the fact that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the $rank(AB)$ when rank of $A$ and $B$ are given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427708/find-the-rankab-when-rank-of-a-and-b-are-given)

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thanks for the response. I can understand Matrix B is invertible. But How do I find Col(A) or Col(AB) without knowing A matrix. only B matrix is known to me. And also how does the rank(AB) is determined based on Col(AB)=Col(A)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde As far I can see from the answers of the other question, it is based on the two matrices are image of one another. But here it is not the case I believe. Please help me with more information relevant to this question. Thanks.